# Non-abelian Chern-Simons forms and Wess-Zumino action

Tags: spacetime, action, branes

Is there any closed analytic relationship between the Wess-Zumino action and the (non-abelian) Chern-Simons forms for arbitrary spacetime dimensions that appear in brane theories?